# Add XmlDocument in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

hi i have xml files and i need to append them like this:

First File:

```
<Tags>
    <Tag name ="1">
        //more xml tags
    </Tag>

    <Tag name = "2">
        //some more xml tags

    </Tag>

    .....

    //add second file here

</Tags>
```

Second File:

```
 <Tag name ="3">
     //more xml tags
 </Tag>
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Ok, I will know from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ImportNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var d1 = new XmlDocument();
d1.LoadXml("<Tags><Tag name =\"1\"></Tag></Tags>");

var d2 = new XmlDocument();
d2.LoadXml("<Tags><Tag name =\"2\"></Tag></Tags>");

var newNode = d1.ImportNode(d2.SelectSingleNode("/Tags/Tag"), true);
d1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);

Console.WriteLine(d1.OuterXml);
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/LTik5K)

Comment: That's not adding anything.

Comment: @Georgi It was just a use case :) See y updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx):

```
var firstDoc = XDocument.Load("file1.xml"); // load 1st file
var tagElement = XElement.Load("file2.xml"); // load <Tag> element from 2nd file
firstDoc.Root.Add(tagElement); // add <Tag> element to 1st file <Tags> element
firstDoc.Save("file1.xml"); // save 1st file
```